# Apache .htaccess convert URL to lowercase if it starts with a certain string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to create a redirect rule to lowercase.

All URLs starting with `/catalog/` must be lowercase. example:

- `/catalog/Foo` => `/catalog/foo`
- `/catalog/Foo/fOO2` => `/catalog/foo/foo2`

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are on Apache 2.4 then you can use the `tolower()` function in an Apache expression in a mod_rewrite `RewriteCond` directive to perform the uppercase to lowercase conversion on these URLs.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond expr "tolower(%{REQUEST_URI}) =~ /(.*)/"
RewriteRule ^catalog/.*[A-Z] %1 [R=302,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* checks for a URL-path that starts `catalog/` followed by an uppercase character. The `RewriteCond` directive then converts the URL-path to lowercase, which is captured in the regex and the corresponding backreference `%1` is used in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string as the target for the redirect. `%1` contains the lowercase'd URL-path.